# Preact Router not replacing history

Tags: preact

In my application, I create pagination that every click on the link it will call route method. I call the method like this inside `onClick` of the link.

```
route(`users/${activePage}/per_page/${per_page}`,true)
```

At first click it is behaving good, it replaces the history, but next click it appends the history, so if it `users/2/per_page/5` before will be appended `/users/2/per_page/users/3/per_page/3`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your onClick handler, return false or call `event.stopPropagation(),event.preventDefault()`:

```
<a href="/page/2" onClick={e => {
  route('/blah', true);
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}}>2</a>
```

FWIW, overriding links with this behavior is generally considered bad for UX/accessibility.

Comment: Apologies I just noticed - your URL is incorrect. It MUST begin with a slash: ```route(`/users/${activePage}/per_page/${per_page}`,true)```